# The Chain Rule. Calculate $h'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $g_1(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $g_2(x,y,z)=x+y+z.$ Let $g(x,y,z)=(g_1,g_2)$ and $f(x,y)=2(x+y).$ Find $h(x,y,z)=(f\circ g)(x,y,z)$ and $h'(c).$

Hello MathStack! My question is about how calculate $h'(c).$ I can find the composition of functions, this is $h(x,y,z)=2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2(x+y+z).$ But $h'(c)=???$

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in to ways, calculate the matrix for the derivative of $g$, calculate the gradient for $f$ and compose them or directly, as we know the explicit form for $h$, calculating the gradient for $h$. Do it following the second way, as $h:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$. Yes, $h'$ is a vector.

$h(x,y,z)=2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2(x+y+z).$

$\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}=4x+2$

$\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial y}=4y+2$

$\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial z}=4z+2$

For $c=(x_c,y_c,z_c)$ we have, $h'(c)=\nabla h(c)=(4x_c+2,4y_c+2,4_cz+2)$

---

**added** The other way,

$g'(r)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial z}\\
  \dfrac{\partial g_2}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial g_2}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}$

$g'(r)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  2x&2y&2z\\
  1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}$

$f'(s)=(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y})=(2,2)$

$h'(c)=(f'·g')(c)=(4x_c+2,4y_c+2,4z_c+2)$